# Override tax rate on programmatically created order

Tags: extensions, tax, quote, programmatically, quoteitem

I'm building an extension which imports orders created on a third-party system into Magento. The third-party system should be the single source of truth for the order's prices, tax rate, tax paid, etc.

When creating a quote item for each order line to be imported, I can successfully override the product's price with `setOriginalCustomPrice` and `setCustomPrice`. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent for the tax rate (or even just the tax paid).

I've attempted using `setTaxPercent`, `setTaxAmount`, `setBaseTaxAmount`, etc. to no avail. I've seen suggestion of hooking into `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`, but I don't want to effect any orders created on the front-end of the Magento store (i.e. orders not from the third-party system).

Can someone please point me in the right direction!

Comment: I think your best bet to be sure that Magento does not mess around with these values is to set them directly on the order object after converting the quote.

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks. I had experimented with that; I wanted to avoid manually calculating the subtotals, totals, etc., but perhaps it's the only way to go

Comment: @AngusFretwell I'm currently struggling with this same issue and am curious if you found a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event '**sales_model_service_quote_submit_success**'
and add the custom value in quote to check the Quote data, and Apply Condition there, So It Won't Effect the frontend orders.

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="vendor_modulename_order_save_quote" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\Order\SaveQuote" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/Order/SaveQuote.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuelName\Observer\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveQuote implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $tax = '67.99'; // tax amount
            $price = '107.99'; // price
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');
            $customOrderFlag = $quote->getData('custom_order'); // This Is the Check For the Custom order
            if (!$customOrderFlag) {
                foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    $sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
                    $item->setTaxAmount($tax); // Setting Custom Tax amount
                    $item->setBaseTaxAmount($tax);
                    $item->save();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Silence
        }
    }
}
```